# Using JSon in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I want send JSONArray of JSONObject to JSP.
How can i iterate over the JSON Array and retrieve data from JSON Object?

After that i tried send ArrayList of JSONObject.So now i can iterate over the list.But how can i get data from JSONObject.?

```
<c:forEach items="${severityList}" var="report">
<p>${report}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

and JSON Object looks like this:

```
{"severity":"1","TOTAL":"5"}
{"severity":"2","TOTAL":"1"}
{"severity":"4","TOTAL":"2"}
{"severity":"5","TOTAL":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to iterate `JSONArray` using `forEach jstl`. It can iterate only things like java `collections`.

If you really want to iterate `JSONArray` then you have to look for other alternatives like using a `for loop` inside `scriptlet`, or by storing the result to `javascript` variable and iterating it in the client side.